# Javascript: Disable iOS scroll-to-top when status bar is tapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile

I've got a site, and I want to disable all scrolling when a lightbox pops up, and then re-enable it when the lightbox is closed.
I've got this:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){
    if (stopScroll) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Which works great for manual scrolling, but the user can still tap the status bar and get taken to the top of the page (and now the lightbox isn't centred anymore, or worse still, totally off the page). I'm using JQuery Mobile. How can I temporarily disable this functionality in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. A better solution to the problem would be to prevent your lightbox from breaking when scrolling occurs by changing the lightbox position to fixed instead of absolute:

```
</style>
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  background:#ccc;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
</style>
<div class="centered">I won't scroll off page</div>
```

Another option is to check for the scroll event and restore the original position:

```
$('.show_popup').on('click', function(){
    var position= $(window).scrollTop(); // save pos        
    // show popup    
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(window).scrollTop(position); // restore pos on scroll
    });
});

$('.hide_popup').on('click', function(){
    $(window).off(); // remove handler
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/5AGPG/)

Comment: I could do this, but I really want the screen to stay fixed. It's meant to emulate the "Share" button on an app, with a full-screen lightbox that prevents scrolling. It's confusing if the "Share" lightbox pops up, and then the user scrolls to the top - are they stil sharing the same item?

Comment: I updated my answer with a second possible solution. It worked when I tested on my iPhone.